# Adjust layout perfectly on all screens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen-size

Hi i have this screen for my app but instead of scrollview i want layout to fit perfectly for every screen size phones. Like i want every layouts to decrease height accordingly if the phone screen height is small.
[image: Fit to every screen perfectly]

There is margin in the bottom, i don't want that extra space.

My XML code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_dashboard">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="150dp"
                android:text="Match Starts in 02:24:39"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/liveMarket"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/badge_critical_charts"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Live Market"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:id="@+id/live_Market"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/card2"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/bookkeeping"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"

                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="My Book"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:id="@+id/MyBook"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/card3"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/charicon_statistics"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"

                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Win|Loss Stats"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:id="@+id/win_loss_stats"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/card4"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/calendar_png_picture"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Schedule"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:id="@+id/Schedule"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/card5"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/pie_chart"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"

                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Poll"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:id="@+id/Poll"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/card6"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/results_icon_png_2"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"

                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Recent Result"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:id="@+id/Recent_Result"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Suggest me a way to do this or point me to the right documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,You should change the cardView height to match parent and add layout_weight to their parent like the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".DashboardActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_dashboard"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!--<ScrollView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent">-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Match Starts in 02:24:39"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/liveMarket"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/badge_critical_charts"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Live Market"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/live_Market"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/bookkeeping"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My Book"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/MyBook"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/winLossCard"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/win_loss_stats">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/charicon_statistics"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Win|Loss Stats"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/card4"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/Schedule">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar_png_picture"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Schedule"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/card5"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/pie_chart"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Poll"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/Poll"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/card6"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/results_icon_png_2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Recent Result"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/Recent_Result"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!--</ScrollView>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed a nested layouts, indent xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_dashboard">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="150dp"
            android:text="Match Starts in 02:24:39"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/liveMarket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/badge_critical_charts" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/live_Market"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:text="Live Market"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookkeeping"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/MyBook"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:text="My Book"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/charicon_statistics"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/win_loss_stats"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:text="Win|Loss Stats"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar_png_picture" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Schedule"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:text="Schedule"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/pie_chart"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Poll"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:text="Poll"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/results_icon_png_2"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Recent_Result"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:text="Recent Result"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```